# I have a picture with a black part that I want to be cut out in c++(example below)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

considering the variable result is the picture i want to be cropped without the black part
this is my code

```
cv::Mat result;
result = img1.clone();
cv::warpPerspective(img1, result, H, cv::Size(img1.cols + img2.cols, img1.rows));
Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(result, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

Mat thresh;
threshold(result, thresh, 1, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
imshow("r", thresh);
waitKey(0);
int max = 0;
int x = 0;
while (thresh.at<uchar>(x, 10) != 0) {
    x++;
    if (max < x)
        max = x;
    //enter code here
}
```

**how can I fix my code?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the general idea:

1. Convert the image to **grayscale**
2. **Threshold** everything that is above `0` using a simple binary threshold
3. Clean the binary image with **morphology**
4. Use the binary mask to get the **largest contour** on the image
5. Use the largest contour to get a **bounding rectangle**
6. Use the bounding rectangle to **crop** the image

Here's the code, first, read the image and convert it to grayscale. Apply a simple `threshold` afterwards. Pretty straightforward:

```
//Read input image:
cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread( "C://opencvImages//DOrOQ.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR );
cv::Mat testImage = inputImage.clone(); //Deep copy for cropping

//Convert to greayscale:
cv::cvtColor( inputImage, inputImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY );

//Threshold everything that is above 0:
cv::Mat binaryMask;
cv::threshold( inputImage, binaryMask, 1, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV );
```

This is the binary mask you get:

[image]

Now, check out the little pixels that survived the operation. We can get rid of these if we apply `Eroding`, followed by `Dilating`. I'm using a rectangular `structuring element` of size `3` and `5` operation iterations:

```
//Clean the mask via Erode + Dilate:
cv::Mat SE = cv::getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3,3) );
int opIterations = 5;
cv::morphologyEx( binaryMask, binaryMask, cv::MORPH_ERODE, SE, cv::Point(-1,-1), opIterations );
cv::morphologyEx( binaryMask, binaryMask, cv::MORPH_DILATE, SE, cv::Point(-1,-1), opIterations );
```

The resulting, filtered, binary mask is this:

[image]

Now, invert the image so the largest white blob is the actual filtered blob. Let's find the largest contour on this image:

```
//Invert Mask:
binaryMask = 255 - binaryMask;

//Lets get the blob contour:
std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

cv::findContours( binaryMask, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );

int largestBlobIndex = 0;
double largestArea = 0.0;

//Find the largest blob adn get the outer contour:
for( int i = 0; i < (int)contours.size(); i++ ) {

    //Find the area of the contour
    double a = cv::contourArea( contours[i], false);
    //Store the index of largest contour:
    if( a > largestArea ){
        largestArea = a;
        largestBlobIndex = i;
    }

}

//Get the bounding box of the biggest blob:
cv::Rect boundingBox = cv::boundingRect( contours[largestBlobIndex] );
```

This bounding box (the red rectangle) encloses the actual area you want to crop:

[image]

Now, just crop the image:

```
//Crop the image:
cv::Mat croppedImage = testImage( boundingBox );
```

And you get the final result:

[image]